# FFMPEG - how to convert large file to much smaller file to view on LG smart TV

Tags: ffmpeg

I have edited a home movie thru Davinci Resolve and the output has been rendered/saved on my PC. For some strange reason it seems huge and nothing will play it (apart from within Resolve itself) and none of my conversion software will convert it from the huge file to something smaller I can watch on my LG smart TV (handbrake, video converter).

I downloaded FFMPEG and installed it, then ran a command to examine the file. Results posted here. Does this mean that FFMPEG has found the codec and I can convert it ? and has anyone any suggestions on what to convert it to ?

Many thanks

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\PAW\Videos\Resolve\untitled.mov

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\PAW\Videos\Resolve\untitled.mo
v':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100

Duration: 01:09:43.81, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 390431 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHR 444) (AVdh / 0x68645641), yuv444p12le(
tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 388894 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn
, 60k tbc (default)

    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s1
6, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
```

Comment: Depends on your build of FFmpeg, but yes, it appears on the surface that you can convert it.  Try it and see.  On another note, this question belongs on SuperUser.  Also, there are a ton of smart TVs out there, and they all have different support for different things.... I guess try h.264 video with AAC audio in an MP4 container?

Comment: The resolution of the video is fine but the bitrate is very high which currently most devices will have trouble decoding fast enough. Reduce this bitrate right down and convert to a format compatible with the TV.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ffmpeg should convert QT DNXHR 444.
For producing h264 file with low bitrate you can try something like:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\PAW\Videos\Resolve\untitled.mov -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 24 outputPath\outputName.mov
```

"crf" will determine the bitrate (in general). The higher the "crf" number the less quality you get.

But I have to say that you can export almost every kind of formats from resolve and I'm not sure you will need ffmpeg at all.

I use ffmpeg in rare accessions where I need a format that resolve can't produce like .hap files.
Many people use ffmpeg for making prores files in a windows machine.